# Titleize and accent in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, internationalization

I use .titleize in my rails app, but I have an undesired result with accent.

Exemple :
For the word Prégneau result with .titleize method is PrÉgneau...

How I can fix this ? Thanks

> 002 > 'PRÉGNEAU'.titleize  => "PrÉgneau"

Comment: I'm unable to replicate that -- `"prégneau".titleize => Prégneau` for me.  What versions are you running?

Comment: @JohnFeltz `'PRÉGNEAU'` and `'prégneau'` are different strings...

Comment: I tested the initial version of the question.  OP edited it since then...

Answer (score 0):

with Rails 4.2.7.1 and ruby 2.3.1 work fine

`Loading development environment (Rails 4.2.7.1)
2.3.1 :001 > 'Prégneau'.titleize
 => "Prégneau"`

What rails and ruby version you use?
Into you project type `rails -v` and `ruby -v`

Comment: Hey, I m using rails 5.0.0 and ruby 2.2.4. The orginal name in DB is  "PRÉGNEAU". Can u try 'PRÉGNEAU".titleize ?

Comment: I replicate you issue. Well this happen with non-english string.
You can try this `'PRÉGNEAU'.mb_chars.titleize.to_s`

ActiveSupport::Multibyte::Chars class which encapsulates the original string. A Unicode safe version of all the String methods are defined on this proxy class. If the proxy class doesn't respond to a certain method, it's forwarded to the encapsulated string.

Comment: Thanks for help. That's really strange because this method work in console, but if I try to implant this on my view it doesn't work i have the same problem... <%= @camping.commune.mb_chars.titleize.to_s %>

Comment: Maybe you should save the value formatted when save @camping. commune =  _comune. mb_chars.titleize.to_s 
so you avoid use mb_chars every time that you load the view

Comment: where i can put this ?